# Focus next input after condition....in ul list jquery

Tags: jquery

I was looking for similar responses on this site, but I wasn't able to make my code work.

What am I doing wrong?

**I want to focus the next input after `alert();`**

I know I need to use `next()` function but...for some reason I don't get it.

*working code below*

```js
$(".insertWord input").on("input", function() {
  var matchWord = $(this).attr("title");

  if ($(this).val() === matchWord) {
    alert();
    $(this).closest('.insertWord input').next().focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='words'>
  <li class='insertWord'><input title='abc' /></li>
  <li class='insertWord'><input title='mnp' /></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try with "change" event instead "input".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `.insertWord input`, you're just selecting the same `<input>` you were on originally.

Instead, you can select with just `.insertWord`, or use the [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method to move up the DOM

```js
// Instead of
$(this).closest('.insertWord input')

// Use
$(this).closest('.insertWord')
// Or
$(this).parent()
```

[`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) isn't able to  traverse *up and down* the DOM; only up, which is why you weren't finding your `<input>` this way.

Also, once you moved to the next `<li>`, you'll have to use [`.find('input')`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to move down to the `<input>`

```js
$(".insertWord input").on("input", function() {
  var matchWord = $(this).attr("title");

  if ($(this).val() === matchWord) {
    alert();
    $(this).closest('.insertWord').next().find('input').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='words'>
  <li class='insertWord'>
    <input title='abc' />
  </li>
  <li class='insertWord'>
    <input title='mnp' />
  </li>
</ul>
```